# Is it more performant to have rows or columns in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, normalization

If I have to save many strings that are related and that may be dividied in different languages: What's the best way to do it?

I think I have the following options. Option 1 and 3 is the most clear solution to me. They have more columns, but result in fewer rows.

Option 2 and 4 are the most flexible ones (I could dynamically add new string_x without changing the database). They have only three columns but they will result in many rows.

Option 5 would result in many tables.

**Option 1:**

```
id | string_1 | string_2 | string_3 | string_4 | ... | string_n | lang
```

**Option 2** *(where name would be string_1 or string_2 etc.)*

```
id | name | lang
```

**Option 3**

```
id | string_1 | string_2 | string_3 | string_4 | ... | string_n
id | lang     | stringid
```

**Option 4**

```
id | lang | stringid
id | name
```

**Option 5**

```
id | string_1 | lang
id | string_2 | lang
id | ...      |lang
```

I'm using it to store precached html values for multiple views (one line view, two lines, long description, etc.), if this is of interest.

Comment: Use option 4. Where, I am guessing first table with following columns: `id | lang | stringid` is your basic table, and another one `id | name`

stores the main string!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1 and 3 are not recommended, as you end up with the language (which is data) in the field name. You have to change the database design if you want to add another language.

Option 5 is not recommended, as you end up with the string identifider (which is data) in the table name. You have to change the database design if you want to add another string.

Option 2 or 4 would work fine. Option 4 is more normalised, as you don't have duplicate string names, but option 2 might be easier to work with if you enter values directly into the table view.

Having many rows in a table is not a problem, that's what the database system is built for.

Comment: "Option 4 is more normalised" -- based on the information in the question, don't see how anyone can say which normal form any of the tables are in.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Option 2 has the string name repeated for each language.

Comment: I'll take option 4 then. Thank you. I guess it'd be better to have the string table reference the language table, as I can reuse the language table, if I might have other datasets that is localized.

Comment: Without knowing what the key for Option 2 is, how can you say what normal form it satisfies? If you can't say what normal form this (or any of the other tables) are in, how can you say that "Option 4 is more normalised"? Rhetorical questions, of course: without the salient facts, no one can say.

Comment: @onedaywhen: I haven't claimed to know which normal form any of the options are in, only that option 4 is more normalised than option 2.

Comment: You can claim what you like :) If you can't demonstrate that option 4 is in first normal form then I don't see how you can demonstrate that option 4 is in a higher normal form than option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've not had to specifically deal with multi-language interfaces, and if that is all its purpose is, is a translation, I would to option 1, but swapped, something like

id  English  French  German  Spanish, etc...

So you would basically have a master column (such as English) as a "primary" word that is always populated, then as available, the other language columns get filled in.  This way, you can keep adding as many "words" as you need, and if they get populated across all the different languages, so be it...  If not, you still have a "primary" value that could be used.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of other things. First of all, how many strings could there be? How many languages could there be? To simplify things, let's say if either of those numbers are greater than 5, then options 1 and 3 are infeasible.

Before I go any further, you should definitely look into implementing multi-language functionality outside of the database. In PHP you can use [Gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) and put your translation data in flat files. This is a better idea for multiple reasons, the main ones being performance and ease of use with external translators.

If you absolutely must do this in a database then you should use a table structure similar to this:

```
id | string | language
```

An example entry would be:

```
welcome_message | Hello, World! | english
```

Which I think you've described in **Option 2**. To clarify, depending on the amount of different languages and different strings, you should use a single table with a fixed number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you support only a few languages, you might also consider a schema in which each language is its own column:

```
ID    EN    ES    FR   Etc...
```

This is less normalized than your option 4, but it is very easy to work with.  We have built our database translations like this.  As we develop code, we create string resources fill in the English text.  Later, a translator fills in the strings of their language.